# How to use collaborative real time editing in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I have installed the ECF 3.6.0 plugin and looked at different threads but cannot find an answer. I read about Cola but even after reading the documentation I couldn't set it up. Does anyone have any ideas about how my partner and I can edit the same file at the same time and see each others changes in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Saros plugin? Following is the link to that plugin.

[Saros plugin for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/saros-distributed-collaborative-editing-and-pair-programming-0#.UqhhOtJgcm8)

Hope this helps you.